# Login users/start session with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to create a login section on my website using PDO.

So far I've the following...

**config.php**

```
    // Connect to DB
    $username = 'user@site.co.uk';
    $password = 'pass';

    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', $username, $password);    
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } 
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

?>
```

**header.php**

```
// DB Config
include '/assets/config.php';

// User Session
$login = 'liam';
$pass = 'password';

$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM access_users WHERE login = ? AND pass = ?");
$sth->bindParam(1, $login);
$sth->bindParam(2, $pass);
$sth->execute();

if ($sth->rowCount() > 0)
{
  // session stuff,
 // refresh page
}  

?>
```

My browser doesn't display the page however, and when I view my source theres no data contained within, can anybody see where im going wrong?

Comment: (1) _never_ store a plaintext password. (2) I see no output being generated.. so... (3) enable display_errors or log_errors, and check out what they are either on screen or in the log.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
// User Session
$login = 'liam';
$pass = 'password';
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
$sth->execute(array(":username" => $login,":password" => $pass));

if ($sth->rowCount() > 0)
{
// session stuff,
// refresh page
  echo $sth->rowCount();
}
```

make sure you have username "liam" and pass "password" in the database

Answer (score 1):

You have set `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. This means, you should wrap your statements in a `try/catch` block and test `execute()`s return code:

```
try {
    $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM access_users WHERE login = ? AND pass = ?");
    $sth->bindParam(1, $login);
    $sth->bindParam(2, $pass);
    if (!$sth->execute()) {
        $info = $sth->errorInfo();
        echo 'Error: ' . $sth->errorCode() . ' (' . $info[2] . ")\n";
    } elseif ($sth->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        // session stuff,
        // refresh page
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

and put some trace statements in, of course.